# ionic v1 md-select with search

Tags: ionic-framework

i tried to make md-select with search field in ionic 1 but when i click search field md-item suddenly close itself

here my html

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="icon-title">
                         <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        <md-select name="shuttleagen" required ng-model="travel.shuttleagen" interface="action-sheet" aria-label="md-option" ng-change="update()" style="border-bottom:1px solid #3B3837; width:70%; ">
                            <md-select-header layout="column" class="demo-select-header">

                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" 
                                    placeholder="Search..."/>
                                </md-input-container>
                            </md-select-header>
                                <md-option value="0" selected="selected">Pilih Agen</md-option>
                                <md-option ng-repeat="data in travelkd | filter:searchTerm" value="{{data.produk_id}}">{{data.produk_nm}}</md-option>

                        </md-select>

                    </md-input-container>
```

Here my js

```
var id = $scope.datauser[0].id;
        apiService.getAll('travel',id,0,$scope.offset,$scope.limit).success(function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
            $scope.travelkd = data;
            //console.log(data);



        }).finally(function() {

          $scope.selected = null;
          $element.find('input').on('keydown', function(ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
          });

            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        });
        //$scope.flightdate = new Date();
```